# How to convert Varchar Date Value into Date Data Type in MySQL using Case When and Str_to Date

Tags: mysql, substring, str-to-date

I have a list of dates in a table that currently holds that column as a Varchar data type. What I am looking to do is clean up this table and the first step is to convert this column into a Date Data Type and convert the values that I have to all be consistent.

The following is my create and insert statements, this is a sample of the Date Column:

Create Table:

```
CREATE TABLE “BU_TABLE_DATES" 
   (           "END_DATE" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)
   );
```

Insert Statements:

```
INSERT INTO "BU_TABLE_DATES" (END_DATE) VALUES ('01/01/2018');
INSERT INTO "BU_TABLE_DATES" (END_DATE) VALUES ('13-Jan-18');
INSERT INTO "BU_TABLE_DATES" (END_DATE) VALUES ('13-Jan-19');
INSERT INTO "BU_TABLE_DATES" (END_DATE) VALUES ('13-Jan-19');
INSERT INTO "BU_TABLE_DATES" (END_DATE) VALUES ('13-Jan-20');
INSERT INTO "BU_TABLE_DATES" (END_DATE) VALUES ('13/01/2018');
INSERT INTO "BU_TABLE_DATES" (END_DATE) VALUES ('13/01/2019');
INSERT INTO "BU_TABLE_DATES" (END_DATE) VALUES ('13/01/2020');
INSERT INTO "BU_TABLE_DATES" (END_DATE) VALUES ('17/07/2017');
INSERT INTO "BU_TABLE_DATES" (END_DATE) VALUES ('17/07/2019');
```

What I would like the final output to look like is the following (all Date datatype)

```
End_Date
01/01/2018
13/01/2018
13/01/2019
13/01/2019
13/01/2020
13/01/2018
13/01/2019
13/01/2020
13/01/2020
17/07/2017
17/07/2019
```

At present I have managed to write the following code using a case statement and str_to_date which helps to convert the values where the month is only a 2 character and also how I can have the format to show the year at the end even the code is written that way.

My Query

```
SELECT
    End_Date,
    CASE End_Date
        WHEN substring(End_Date,2,1) = '-' THEN STR_TO_DATE (End_Date,'%d-%m-%Y')
        WHEN substring(End_Date,2,1) = '/' THEN STR_TO_DATE (End_Date,'%d/%m/%Y')
    ELSE STR_TO_DATE (End_Date,'%d/%m/%Y') END as End_Date_New
FROM
    BU_TABLE_DATES
;
```

Output

```
End_Date    End_Date_New
01/01/2018  2018-01-01
13-Jan-18   (null)
13-Jan-19   (null)
13-Jan-19   (null)
13-Jan-20   (null)
13/01/2018  2018-01-13
13/01/2019  2019-01-13
13/01/2020  2020-01-13
13/01/2020  2020-01-13
17/07/2017  2017-07-17
17/07/2019  2019-07-17
```

Lastly in the code I am creating a new column, but I want to just change the datatype of the existing column but at present found a way to create a new column and then thought it might be best to then remove the old column, but ideally want this to work on the 1 column.

Would love some advice on how best to tackle this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Save yourself a world of misery, and store dates using a date data type

Comment: @Strawberry this is what OP is trying to do!

Comment: Thanks guys for your responses. Unfortunately the reason for using Varchar was because of the discrepancies of this column from csv files hence the reason of now going through the cleanup process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following to convert the strings to dates. You really should use `DATE`-datatype when you store dates. Using `VARCHAR` for dates will only get you into trouble.

```
SELECT
  End_Date,
  CASE substring(End_Date,3,1)
    WHEN '-' THEN STR_TO_DATE(End_Date,'%d-%b-%y')
    WHEN '/' THEN STR_TO_DATE(End_Date,'%d/%m/%Y')
  END as End_Date_New
FROM 
  BU_TABLE_DATES
```

See [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) statement and the [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)-function parameters (same as `DATE_FORMAT`'s) from the manual.

Comment: Thanks slaakso, that did the trick, is there anyway to do it on the same column itself, or do I have to do it on a new column? Lastly is there a link or something just to understand '%d-%b-%y' rather than a copy/paste job from my end as want to learn as to what is going on in the code.

Comment: You better add a `date` column, use `update`-statement to convert the strings to date and then drop the `varchar`-column. See the links to the manual pages.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, how would you deal with a value that had no "day" element so for example "January 2019", i am guessing you would have to completely change the case statement as there wouldn't be a divider value "/" or "-" as well right? Btw, my question has been answered, this is just to understand more elements of date values.

Comment: @MichaelOwen A date has day, month and the year part. If your data has only the month and the year, you would need to decide what day that string represents (first / last / some other day) in that month. If your data has more arbitrary notations for date in `varchar`, you might want to consider making a function that parses the data and produces the date. With a function you would have more flexibility on parsing the data than with simple `CASE`-statement.